# Not able to use Django mongodb engine with Django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have django installed on my server with pymongo and mongoengine.My django project settings.py file :

```
# Django settings 

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'RTSdatabase',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '27017',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 't!0pa3z_(gzlb(sai&f$zs4cz9_2u=u(6&g99swo%psrastav6'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RTS.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'RTS.RESTAPI',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

whenever i try to access the project it gives me error:

> Exception Value:   'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database
>   backend.  Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
>       'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3' Error was: No module named django_mongodb_engine.base

I dont know what am I doing wrong here in settings file.I am following http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/django_python_mongodb_engine_mongo for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in that linked article has `django_mongodb_engine.mongodb` for the `ENGINE` setting.

You'll also need django-nonrel for this to work.

Comment: django-nonrel is already installed and I have tried both django_mongodb_engine.mongodb and django_mongodb_engine in 'Engine' name but it still giving me same error

Comment: Oh i found the problem ,I was using the wrong package of django mongodb.Now I installed the right package and it started working. Thanks

Comment: @anks: its awesome if you mention correct package name, very easy to us

Comment: @daniel, problem with `django-nonre` is that it downgrades your django package to 1.5, for any one using django ver 1.5+, its a nightmare.....i was following [tutorial](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html) when i realized this!!

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your depended packages is installed correctly.
2. you can follow [installation](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html) to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the default django installation by

```
sudo pip uninstall django
```

and reinstalled from Django fork(https://github.com/django-nonrel/django) with support for NoSQL databases by

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django
```

and remove/comment `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` from `setting.py`

```
# 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
# 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
```